# ajax loaded twice in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ajax, controller

I'm a begginer with `angularjs` ,I'v created a `crud` and it work fine, but my problem is that when I load for the first time the page and when I checked the `console` , I see that the `ajax` (that is in the controller `"AgentController"` ) who load the personnel list is called twice , knowing that two views (add form and edit form) use this same `controller.` here is my code:

```
crudApp.controller("AgentController",['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){
            $http.post('databaseFiles/slct_agent.php').then(function( Response )
            {
                    var data_agent = $.map( Response , function(value, index) {
                        return [ value ];
                    });                 
                    var aResult_agent = data_agent[ 0 ];                        
                    $scope.agents = aResult_agent;              
            });
    }]);
```

Thank you for the response.

Comment: can you share your HTML and route file?

Comment: Also are you sure it's actually making a call twice? If on developer tools you go to the network tab you should be able to see exagtly what xhttp requests are being made.

Comment: Hi , this is my html code :    <pre> <code> <div class="form-group">
       <label for="select">Responsable : </label>
       <select   multiple id="slct_agent" class="form-control"  ng-model="traitementsDetails.matricule_resp" >
      <option  ng-repeat="agent in agents track by $index" value="{{agent.matricule}}">{{agent.nom +" "+agent.prenom }}</option>
       </select>
    </div></code></pre>